# Where can I find out about new demos that came out on PS3?

Tags: ps3

Where can I find the newest demos available for PS3? I would rather check them out from my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find them on the PlayStation website listed under Games and doing some filtering on demos.

The current link is http://us.playstation.com/ps-products/BrowseGames?console=ps3&downloadableContent=GameDemos&beginsWith=Any

The problem is, these are for the US. Your profile shows Poland (might try http://pl.playstation.com/ps3/games/ to see if you can find Demos listed there), so I assume there may be some differences in what is available for your region. The other problem is, this link will likely end up changing at some point and time, so this isn't a real helpful answer and/or question.

Comment: just like a game might change after a patch?

Comment: great example would be a stalker game. after installing a patch old savegames don't work.